# Find the inserted keys of an array in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

In the below code, I am expected to print k1,k2 and k3. It is printing v1,v2 v3

```
declare -A ARRAY_NAME
ARRAY_NAME[k1]="v1"
ARRAY_NAME[k2]="v2"
ARRAY_NAME[k3]="v3"

for key  in "${ARRAY_NAME[@]}"
        do
                echo "Key -- $key"

        done
```

Please help to resolve this

Comment: Please take a look here [is there a way to list all 'indexes IDs' (keys) on a bash associative array variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91943/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-indexes-ids-keys-on-a-bash-associative-array-vari)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are using associative array. By default these arrays will provide values.

To get Keys of the array, try using exclamation (!).

Below is the updated code

```
for key  in "${!ARRAY_NAME[@]}"
        do
                echo "Key -- $key"

        done
```

Hope this helps.